# What is the problem of this Update query by cursor in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has a column order_id,type int and they are 30 numbers from 1 to 30 and unique.

I'd like to update this column **randomly** by query in MySQL but they must still be **unique** and in **range of 1 to 30**.
I tried this but it has problem is "phpmyadmin"  in server and doesn't show the problem! 
Does anybody know what is the problem?

```
declare Qid2 int;
declare counter int;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

declare c cursor
set c = cursor for select order_id from Table_1
open c;
fetch next from c into Qid2;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
while !done DO


  set Qid2 = (select RAND()*30);
  set counter = ( select count(*) from Table_1 where order_id = Qid2);
  while counter!=0 do
    Begin
      set Qid2 = (select RAND()*30);
       set counter =( select count(*) from Table_1 where order_id = Qid2);
    End while;
  update Table_1
  set order_id = Qid2  where current of c;
  fetch next from c ;


End while;
close c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without going anywhere near the logic i can identify 6 errors (possibly 7 if you haven't set delimiters. I corrected the obvious ones.

```
drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$
create procedure p()
begin 
declare Qid2 int;
declare counter int;
declare order_id int; #error 3 not declared
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

declare c cursor for select order_id from Table_1; #error 1 incorrect syntax
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE; #error 2 wrong position in code

open c;
fetch next from c into Qid2;

while !done DO


  set order_id = (select RAND()*30); #error 3 not declared
  set counter = ( select count(*) from Table_1 where order_id = Qid2);
  while counter!=0 do
    #Begin      #error 4 not required
      set Qid2 = (select RAND()*30);
       set counter =( select count(*) from Table_1 where order_id = Qid2);
    End while;
  #update Table_1
  # set order_id = Qid2  where current of c; #error 5 where? commented out
  fetch next from c into Qid2 ; #error 6 into missing.


End while;
close c;

end $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: This query which you edited has more than 20 errors in my server! It has error in every "declare " word and "$$" and the word "while" and so on...

Comment: Because you are not setting the default delimiter in phpmyadmin perhaps.

Comment: I am sorry sir, but I'm really new in MySQL and I don't know what is this delimiter and how to define it! Is there any article for more details, perhaps?

Comment: The logic of this query is completely true. Actually it was in SQL Server and it was working well but I wanted to transform it to MySQL language.

Comment: I've deleted "$$" and I replaced it by ";;" and it worked but it returned empty result and I know why! I think it's because of this line "set order_id = Qid2  where current of c". I deleted Where current of c, because it isn't in MySQL language but it is very important that shows **"the current line"** . how we can write it in MySQL?

Comment: Is it possible to update the row by cursor in MySQL at all?

Comment: Here's a link to mysql stored programs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html where delimiters are discussed. You also need to check phpmyadmin documentation.

Comment: You are fetching the current cursor record into qid2 so changing the update to where order_id = qid2 may be what you want - BUT you are reusing qid2 so you need another variable to store the rand value.

Comment: I did it and store it to another variable, but still it doesn't do update, I think MySQL's cursor doesn't do update at all. anyway thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (i INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);


 SELECT * 
   FROM
      ( SELECT i 
             , @x:=@x+1 x 
          FROM 
             ( SELECT i FROM my_table ORDER BY RAND())a, (SELECT @x:=0) vars
       ) n
   ORDER 
      BY i;
+---+------+
| i | x    |
+---+------+
| 1 |    7 |
| 2 |    2 |
| 3 |    4 |
| 4 |    9 |
| 5 |    3 |
| 6 |    8 |
| 7 |    1 |
| 8 |    6 |
| 9 |    5 |
+---+------+
```

Comment: Thank you sir but I tried this and it had two problems: first, It is an insert operation not update. second it shows error in ")n" line

Comment: Second: that's plainly not true. First: Adapting this SELECT to an UPDATE is straightforward enough. Third: You wouldn't normally store an easily derivable result

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't catch it! you mean I should have two columns , one in order and second change them randomly? I'm new to MySQL but it seems column x wouldn't store in database, right? I'd like to change that column which is already stored in database cause I need it later.

Comment: Updated to spell everything out - but it's still unlikely that you would need to store this kind of thing.